# Run time error 2185

Tags: ms-access, vba

I getting a `run time error 2185`, *"You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus ..."*.

This is my code that I am using.

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Dim cardno As Integer
    cardno = cardnumber.Text
    DoCmd.OpenForm "search_card_number", acNormal, , WHERE & cardno = [Account Number]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 14):

Referencing the `.Text` property of a control requires it to have focus.
Simply drop that and it should work (the default is `.Value`)

**OR**

Try putting in the SetFocus method as advised by Access, i.e.

```
  Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Dim cardno As Integer

     cardnumber.SetFocus   <-------Use this line to set the focus        

    cardno = cardnumber.Text
  DoCmd.OpenForm "search_card_number", acNormal, , WHERE & cardno = [Account Number]
 End Sub
```

Comment: I get a runtime error 6, overflow. but the carnumber.text did get the value I was enter in textbox

Comment: I guess data can no longer be
held by an integer. Try changing the line

     `Dim cardno As Integer`
to
     
     `Dim cardno As Long` 

should fix the immediate problem.

Comment: I get a 2465 runtime error, and is highlighted the Docmd section in yellow.

Answer (score 1):

That run time error means `You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.`

You can use `.Text` when a control has the focus.

Comment: if I change the text to textbox, I get a data and method member not found

Comment: use `cardno = cardnumber` instead of `cardno = cardnumber.Text`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to test to see if the control had focus before updating the control property,

Here I am updating a combo box search to a wild card search

```
Private Sub Combo_Change()
    'Note control passed to after update sub, then returns to change sub where error occurs
    'Combo is the name of your combo box

    If (Combo Is Me.ActiveControl) Then
        Me.Combo.RowSource = _
            "SELECT [CCL sites v Contract No].ContractID, [CCL Sites].[Site Address], [CCL sites v Contract No].[Contract No] " & _
            "FROM [CCL sites v Contract No] INNER JOIN [CCL Sites] ON [CCL sites v Contract No].SiteID = [CCL Sites].SiteID " & _
            "WHERE [CCL Sites].[Site Address] LIKE '*" & Me.Combo.Text & "*' " & _
            "ORDER BY [CCL Sites].[Site Address]"

        Me.Combo.Dropdown

    End If

End Sub
```